# Ionic V4 ngOnDestroy in root page of app causing problems

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have observable subscriptions in the both home page and first child route of my Ionic V4 app. As a good practice I am using ngOnDestroy methods in both pages and unsubscribing to these subscriptions, within each page, respectively.

The 1st time I route away from the home page and return, the ngOnDestroy method in the **home page** is being called. Subsequently, anytime I nav away from the home page ngOnDestroy is called. However, ngOnDestroy in the first child route works as I expect - I can route to subsequent children and when I return ngOnDestroy is not called, but when I route home then the first child ngOnDestroy is run.

This does not appear much when running `ionic serve`, however when doing an iOS production build, `ionic cordova ios --prod --aot` and run on my device of the iSO simulator this behavior appears.

I had previously asked a somewhat [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976777/ionic-angularfire2-best-practice-for-unsubscribing-to-observables), but it seems that ionViewDidLeave is run even when routing to children and ionViewDidLeave is never run. [V4 documentation](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration/#lifecycle-events) suggests using angular lifecycle hooks anyway.

Is there an explanation for this? Do I even need the home page ngOnDestroy? Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my issue was I had 2 routes to the home page:
`{path: '', component: SlEventsComponent},`
`{path: 'sl-event', component: SlEventsComponent},`
I believe the app was starting on the initial route, but when I nav'd back I went to sl-event.

I've just removed sl-event route and looks like I expect.